# JQ only returns one CIDR block from AWS CLI

Tags: jq, aws-cli

I am trying to read the CIDR blocks from the VPCs in AWS on the AWS CLI. I will use this in a script when I'm done. I am using `jq` to parse the info:

```
 aws ec2 describe-vpcs --region=us-east-1  | jq -r '.Vpcs[].CidrBlock'
10.200.3.0/24
```

However, `jq` only returns one of the two CIDR blocks in the VPC. This is the original json:

```
{
  "Vpcs": [
    {
      "CidrBlock": "10.200.3.0/24",
      "DhcpOptionsId": "dopt-d0aa95ab",
      "State": "available",
      "VpcId": "vpc-00de11103235ec567",
      "OwnerId": "046480487130",
      "InstanceTenancy": "default",
      "Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet": [
        {
          "AssociationId": "vpc-cidr-assoc-09f19d81c2e4566b9",
          "Ipv6CidrBlock": "2600:1f18:1f7:300::/56",
          "Ipv6CidrBlockState": {
            "State": "associated"
          },
          "NetworkBorderGroup": "us-east-1"
        }
      ],
      "CidrBlockAssociationSet": [
        {
          "AssociationId": "vpc-cidr-assoc-0511a5d459f937899",
          "CidrBlock": "10.238.3.0/24",
          "CidrBlockState": {
            "State": "associated"
          }
        },
        {
          "AssociationId": "vpc-cidr-assoc-05ad73e8c515a470f",
          "CidrBlock": "100.140.0.0/27",
          "CidrBlockState": {
            "State": "associated"
          }
        }
      ],
      "IsDefault": false,
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "environment",
          "Value": "int01"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Name",
          "Value": "company-int01-vpc"
        },
        {
          "Key": "project",
          "Value": "company"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Why does `jq` only return part of the info I'm after? I need to get all VPC CIDR blocks in the output.

Comment: The "why" is that you're only asking it for `CidrBlock`s that are directly under `Vpcs`. The other ones are under `Vpcs.CidrBlockAssociationSet`, and you aren't requesting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two keys `CidrBlock` and `CidrBlockAssociationSet` under the `Vpcs` array.

```
aws ec2 describe-vpcs --region=us-east-1 |
  jq -r '.Vpcs[] | .CidrBlock, .CidrBlockAssociationSet[].CidrBlock'

10.200.3.0/24
10.238.3.0/24
100.140.0.0/27
```

Answer (score 1):

and this is an invariant solution:

```
aws ... | jq -r '.. | if type == "object" and has("CidrBlock") then .CidrBlock else empty end'
```

and, inspired by [jq170727's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61047163/11385808), a less expressive form:

```
aws ... | jq -r '.. | objects | .CidrBlock // empty'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a filter inspired by [Dmitry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61046815/8379597) which is slightly shorter: `.. | .CidrBlock? | values`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVRNb9swDL3nVxg@x65kW/66DOsKDMGA9tCil6EHRqI3t47kWYqLostvz2Q3sZ2mDbZhu8ii@fhIPlG6/7Hd@r7z0/E/laI5rxR/@GCtFqo16u32eeY47m3NtZs7X@3ecZ771f4d8NblUuIHhPihT86CyJ3vMRffeX1Vm1JJvRAdTqjaeIIAZAyWI@7agMHODy2UFSwrHH02@0tsW3OPEIGUUhIGIUPO4mTEXT1KbF6QJIqjlERpQkMyAhZSG5Acb1Daz1NfDhawrswEU7fx0NhHrRUvoSv/Gs2gwFSFPmiCGyvllsWDzuORrKCZSCkPMGJxvMyGfMc5u/AgJiSnBU3tkuShNfIzFp8I2ss3repA1V2BKNwJYnNAeInmUTUP56oR2Hxu1LruItfaQ9DGo2PgZre7mx9Nwj8TjFEKTEQsK7IwSbNXgh1NXpi@nrxD3F/qM3tDqT/sA0QSYsoZZRAlpDjZB/FpRHzSNZL8r0aOzm6hL3Z3IHcKqDQOnhv4pt8/wi/YXyCUbdkouUJpDku@7R6QDlFKQ6bTMz/JdwkrfIeIq1UN8snrCT2r9G@T1o26R25O874x4LO9dTfb/AI)